# Why is a file being saved to a different directory path in NetBeans?

Tags: java, file, netbeans, directory

For some unusual reason, when I am using `FileWriter` for *Java Netbean*, the file gets written into this directory:

> C:\Users\myname\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\7.2\config\GF3\domain1

rather than to my working directory, which is at the desktop.

I used this code to check my User Directory, and it returns this:

> System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
>   INFO: C:\Users\myname\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\7.2\config\GF3\domain1

which is obviously NOT my working directory where my source code is. I thought I could have accidentally configured Netbeans to change the directory, but I checked through NetBeans menu and can't figure out how to undo this.

I have never had this problem before in my previous projects. As simple as the following code, the file should appear in my working directory.

```
File file = new File("myFile.xml");
```

Instead now I'm being forced to enter the path name to make the file save into my working directory, which is not going to be dynamic if I change computer.

```
String dir = "C:\\Users\\myname\\Desktop\\Assignment\\IRAssignmentJ\\";
File file = new File(dir + "myFile.xml");
```

Please enlighten me how do I solve this.

Answer (score 1):

> rather than to my working directory, which is at the desktop

No it isn't. The current working directory is whereever the file got saved, by definition. If Netbeans chooses to change directory to where it was saved, there's nothing you can do about it. If you want it in your home directory, there is a system property for that. If you want it saved somewhere else, use a full pathname.

But the behaviour of the application under Netbeans is of little interest. What matters is when you run it as though standalone, like a customer would.

Comment: Are you serious that NetBeans can choose to save some where else and there is nothing I can do about it? Because I am certain that in my previous project, it was never like this. In that case if I send this code to my friend, won't he have to go to the code and change the path himself?

Comment: You proved it yourself when you printed the system property "user.dir". You seem to be confused between 'working directory ... where my source code is' and 'working directory' as known to the operating system. They don't have to be the same thing.